# How to add an empty new line between concatenated files?

Tags: python

I'm concadenating files with this:

```
filenames = ['ch01.md', 'ch02.md', 'ch03.md', 'ch04.md', 'ch05.md']
with open('chall.md', 'w') as outfile:
  for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as infile:
      outfile.write(infile.read())
```

The problem is, I end up with this:

```
## Title 1

Text 1
## Title 2

Text 2
```

And I want this:

```
## Title 1

Text 1

## Title 2

Text 2
```

How to modify the script so it does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them explicitly by iterating over every line in `infile` and adding two line-breaks `\n\n` every time you write a line to `outfile`:

```
with open(fname) as infile:
  for line in infile:
      outfile.write(line + "\n\n")
```

***Edit:*** If you need to write after *every file* you can simply write new lines after every file you process, `write()` takes any string as an argument and writes it:

```
    with open(fname) as infile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
    outfile.write("\n\n")
```

Comment: With what editor are you opening the file? Because fore example notepad on Windows doesn't recognize `\n` as newline character.

Comment: Oh, no. It worked but it's adding a new line after every paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, because you shouldn't iterate over every line in the file. Just do `outfile.write(infile.read() + "\n\n")`.

Comment: Hey it works but for some reason there are two spaces before each `## Title`.

Comment: And your files contain no spaces before `##  Title`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing after each line (as Dimitris Jim suggested) write after each file:

```
with open('chall.md', 'w') as outfile:
  for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as infile:
      outfile.write(infile.read())
    outfile.write("\n\n")
```

Comment: Hey it works but for some reason there are two spaces before each `## Title`.

Comment: @alexchenco Hmm... you might want to call `.strip()` on each of the lines as you write them;  sounds like there's some extra spaces in the file itself.